# how to open and control document?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a USB tablet that behaves as a monitor where i want to display a Win32 Window, this is easy by using CreateWindow, but i also need that the user picks up documents in a list from such window and display them in that very same monitor.

I cannot use CreateProcess since i don't know the application that would open the document, if i use ShellExecuteEx to open a Word document i can get the PID of the process and iterating in the EnumWindows callback get the actual Window, however i've found this to be error prone, when an image document (jpg, png, etc.) is opened, the PID in the structure SHELLEXECUTEINFO call to ShellExecuteEx is NULL. Also this procedure is prone to fail since there Acrobat or Word can keep multiple documents under the same PID. So how do you gurus solve this problem? (open a document at a certain location)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [`SHELLEXECUTEINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure has a `hMonitor` member that lets you specify a monitor to use, but whether the application respects this or not is up to the application, so you may find it doesn't always work. To use it, set the `SEE_MASK_HMONITOR` flag and obtain the monitor handle from one of the [Multiple Display Monitor functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145072(v=vs.85).aspx).

Unfortunately there's no completely reliable way to identify the "main window" of an application that opened a particular file.

Comment: Word and Acrobat observes the last location where a document was closed rather than that property.

Comment: @user311174 Exactly, it's up to the application whether it respects it or not. There's no way to do it reliably, which is what I said.

Comment: I didn't say you were wrong, indeed i upvoted your answer. When i have more time i'd like to explore a solution with WebExplorer and expose it here if correct, otherwhise i'll accept your answer (the question was to try control a document no matter how)

Answer (score 0):

While all Jonathan Potter said was right, it seems like this can be done with COM, there's not much literature in Stackoverflow to put a link to, so i'd rather put a minimal example i found in internet to control size and position of IE.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "Mshtml.h"

void testme(void * ptr )
{
    RECT * rect = (RECT *)ptr;
    CLSID clsid;
    LPUNKNOWN punk = NULL;
    IWebBrowser2 *pWB = NULL;
    IHTMLDocument2 *pHTML = NULL;
    IHTMLElementCollection *pElement = NULL;
    IDispatch *pdisp = NULL;
    DISPID  dispidNamed = DISPID_PROPERTYPUT;
    VARIANT_BOOL bBusy;
    VARIANT var;

    OleInitialize(NULL);
    CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("InternetExplorer.Application"), &clsid);
    CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_SERVER, IID_IUnknown, (LPVOID *)&punk);
    punk->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (LPVOID *)&pWB);
    pWB->put_Visible(TRUE);
    pWB->put_Height(300);
    pWB->put_Top(rect->top);
    pWB->put_Left(rect->left);
    pWB->put_Width(rect->right - rect->left);
    pWB->put_Height(rect->bottom - rect->top);  


    BSTR bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"http://localhost:8080"); //Set web page on  IE
    var.vt = VT_I4;
    var.lVal = 0;   
    pWB->Stop();
    pWB->Navigate(bstrVal, &var, &var, &var, &var);
    SysFreeString(bstrVal); 
    struct info info;

    long IE_HWND = 0;
    if (pWB->get_HWND(&IE_HWND) != S_OK) 
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Failed: pWB->get_HWND");
        return;
    }

    pWB->Release();
    punk->Release();
    OleUninitialize();
}
```

Now if you want IE to show the document rather than download, put a content in the response like:
"Content-disposition", "inline; _file_name_.pdf"